# 3-tier navigation using only CSS

Tags: css, html, navigation

I want to create a 3-level navigation bar like the one on http://www.bestbuy.com/
However, I wanted to know if there was a way I could do this using only CSS. I already tried a navigation bar similar to the one on http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/design-tutorials/how-to-build-and-enhance-a-3-level-navigation-menu/ . However, the problem is that the third level of navigation does not float to the top like the one in best buy. Can somebody show me how to do this using only CSS. Thanks in advanced!

Comment: It's unlikely you're going to find anything EXACTLY like what you want.  That means you will have to learn how the code works and make changes to it to achieve your specific needs.  Downloading something and giving up because it's not exactly what you want is just going to lead to lots and lots of frustration.  If you like something, other than where it puts it's menu, just figure out how it works and change it.  Oh, and the menu you linked to is not purely css, it uses jquery as well.

Comment: Also, you will probably find CSS only menus to be frustrating.  The problem with the CSS only menus is that they're intolerant of accidental mouse movements.  If you accidently move the mouse off an item then the whole menu disappears instantly, forcing you to re-navigate.  javescript based menus can add timeouts so that if you accidently mouse off, you can move back within the timeout period and the menu will not close on you.  This is important if you have users that are elderly, or who have hand-eye coordination issues.

Comment: @MystereMan Sorry, the link I posted was just to show an example of what I had already done using only CSS. I was not able to post a link to my work because I am doing that offline. I wanted to do this using only css because in my opinion I found it to be much simpler.

Comment: Then post your work on a site like jsFiddle.net where you can get the answer you're REALLY looking for, which is how to make the 3rd menu appear where you want it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty simple. With a structure like

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href='#'>level 0</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>level 1</a>
          <ul>
            <li>level 2</li>
<!-- and so on... -->
```

you just need this CSS to make it work

```
nav ul { padding: 0; list-style: none; }
nav>ul>li { float: left; position: relative; }
nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%; left: 0;
}
nav ul ul ul { top: 0; left: 100%; }
nav li:hover>ul { display: block; }
```

## [*demo*](http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/Lsekz)